# List Processing. Indexing rows and columns

Tags: python

I'm struggling with indexing of rows and columns contained within list data structure. The objective is to return the coordinates of '.' in the form of tuple contained within a new list.

The code is given as 3x3 below. The answer should be [(0,0)].

```
lst = [['.', 'x', 'x'],
         ['x', 'x', 'x'],
         ['x', 'x', 'x']]
```

The code I wrote is:

```
def coor(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for row in lst:
        for col in row:
            if col == '.':
                r = lst.index(row)
                c = lst.index(col)
                new_lst.append((r,c))
    return new_lst
```

However, the code is wrong. I thought by calling the index of row which is the first list, it should return 0, and calling the index of col returns 0 as well.

Comment: use `enumerate` instead of `index`

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` will help you here:

```
def coor(lst):
    new_lst = []

    for row_index, row in enumerate(lst):
        for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == '.':
                new_lst.append((row_index, col_index))

    return new_lst
```

Result of `coor(lst)` is `[(0, 0)]`.

As for why your original code didn't work in the first place, you needed to change `c = lst.index(col)` to `c = row.index(col)`, as each `col` is contained within a `row`.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [['.', 'x', 'x'],
     ['x', 'x', 'x'],
     ['x', 'x', '.']]
row_index = [lst.index(item) for item in lst if '.' in item]
tuples = [(idx,lst[idx].index(cell)) for idx in row_index for cell in lst[idx] if cell=='.']
```

output is [(0,0),(2,2)]

explain to the code. 
- row_index, this line is to find all rows which contains '.', store the row index into an list.
- tuples, 2 level for loop. The first for loop - visit every index in row_index, so it only visit row#0 and row#2. The second loop, visit every element in that row, and only store it's index when it equals '.'

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out all such indices with:

```
indices = [(row_idx,col_idx) for col_idx, row in enumerate(lst) for row_idx, element in enumerate(row) if element =='.']
```

In your case: you may use this inside your function as:

```
lst = [['.', 'x', 'x'],
         ['x', 'x', 'x'],
         ['x', 'x', 'x']]

def coor(lst):
    return [(row_idx,col_idx) for col_idx, row in enumerate(lst) for row_idx, element in enumerate(row) if element =='.']
```